# Why not assigned images are not creating, but usual widgets can exist even without assign to variable?

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's start with a code example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
l = tk.Label()  # default name
l1 = tk.Label(name="assign1")
l2 = tk.Label(name="assign2")
l3 = tk.Label(name="assign3")
tk.Label(name="not_assign1")
tk.Label(name="not_assign2")
tk.Label()  # default name
tk.Label(name="not_assign4")

print("\n".join(root.children))
root.mainloop()
```

And output is:

[image]

As can be seen, every label has been created even that has not been assigned to any variable. That will happen with any widgets, so putting into variable is optional. That is ok. Then I decided to do something similar with PhotoImages:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
im = tk.PhotoImage()  # default name
im1 = tk.PhotoImage(name="assign1")
im2 = tk.PhotoImage(name="assign2")
im3 = tk.PhotoImage(name="assign3")
tk.PhotoImage(name="not_assign1")
tk.PhotoImage(name="not_assign2")
tk.PhotoImage()  # default name
tk.PhotoImage(name="not_assign4")

print([im for im in root.image_names() if ":" not in im])  # check ' : ' not to show default icons
root.mainloop()
```

Output is `['assign3', 'pyimage1', 'assign1', 'assign2']`. So no not_assign images at all.

There is actually no need for me to use not assigned images. Just want to know, why this happens.

P.S. This question seems quite trivial, so sorry, if there are already such questions exist.

Comment: If a Label continues to exist in memory even when it is no longer referenced, that's a tiny amount of wasted memory - I'd guess a few hundred bytes at most, although I can't think of any easy way to actually measure it.  If a PhotoImage continues to exist in memory even when it is no longer referenced, that's potentially *megabytes* of wasted space, that cannot be reclaimed as long as your program is running.  Thus the differing behavior in memory management between the two types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is an answer to "why", without asking the person who implemented the `PhotoImage` class. It could be argued that this is a bug in the design of image handling in tkinter, but maybe the designers had a reason for making it work this way.

Comment: Thanks. Then I will try to massage developers (probably they will not reply).

Comment: Might be weakref vs ref difference, done for reasons of memory consumption